# Find all columns with null values for every record based ID field - Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, null, isnull, recode

Help Please, How can I show the result where all column values are null? For example, I have a table like this: (There are 51 columns/fields in this table), I want to check each record and if the records have complete null for the ID, then that record should be the output.

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col25 | Col50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | *Null* | JAC | *Null* |
| 2 | *Null* | EFG | PQR | *Null* |
| **3** | *Null* | *Null* | *Null* | *Null* |
| 4 | HIJ | JQR | POT | MNO |

And I want my result to look like below:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col25 | Col50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | *Null* | *Null* | *Null* | *Null* |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the fields:

```sql
Select * From YourTable
Where (Col1 & Col2 & ... & Col50) Is Null
```

Using VBA and DAO to check a single Id:

```
Public Function CheckNulls(ByVal Id As Long) As Boolean

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Field   As DAO.Field
    
    Dim AllNull As Boolean
    
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From YourTable Where Id = " & Id & "")
    
    If Records.RecordCount = 1 Then
        For Each Field In Records.Fields
            If Field.Name = "Id" Then
                Set Field = Nothing
            ' Check for Null:
            ElseIf Not IsNull(Field.Value) Then
                Exit For
            ' Check for zero length string:
            ElseIf Nz(Field.Value) <> "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Records.Close
    
    AllNull = (Field Is Nothing)
    
    CheckNulls = AllNull
    
End Function
```

Used in a query:

```sql
SELECT 
    Id, CheckNulls([Id]) AS AllNull
FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE 
    CheckNulls([Id]) = True;
```

Comment: I would like to loop through each column instead of adding each 50 column to SQL

Comment: Well, then do so. But you stated, that you would list all records matching the criterium, and the fastest method for that is to use a query.

Comment: I am sorry, but because the number of columns is high, I would like to have VBA code, instead a query. I am looking for the VBA code where first it should check all the columns (50) automatically and give the result if all the columns are null for an ID. And also a number of records in this table is around 50000

Comment: Then  loop the _Fields_ collection of the recordset.

Comment: I am new to VBA can you please guide me on this

Comment: Yes. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Am I interpreted wrongly,
the above code gives all records, and I think it should loop through all the col1-col50 and if all are empty then it should list the ID as in my first post.

Comment: That it will do. If not, at least one field is not _Null_ (empty).

Comment: But I need only the records in which all the fields (col1 to col50) are Null (empty)

Comment: Then filter as shown. See edited answer, please.

Comment: I am really sorry, It gives empty records, can you please check the two tables in my question, I need only the records in which all the fields (col1 to col50) are Null (empty) and with each ID. in my sample table ID=3 of the col1-col50 are null values, I need those records only.

Comment: Then, perhaps you have _zero length string_ values. See expanded answer, please.

Comment: Same no records showing

Comment: Sorry, code is verified, so your data are not what you think they are.

Comment: Sorry, I even check with the sample table as shown in my question. but the same result.

Comment: Well, it works here, so double-check everything.

Comment: Thanks for your support I got workaround from your code

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered, if you feel so, and/or post your revised code.